# How to find Next Image src with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have my HTML code like

```
<div id="thumbs" class="content mThumbnailScroller">
<ul>
  <li><img src="images/ind_thumb.jpg" alt="1st image description" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/pak_thumb.jpg" alt="2nd image description" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/thi_thumb.jpg" alt="3rd image description" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/maye_thumb.jpg" alt="4th image description" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/singa_thumb.jpg" alt="5th image description" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/keniya_thumb.jpg" alt="6th image description" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/aus_thumb.jpg" alt="7th image description" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/uae_thumb.jpg" alt="8th image description" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/wi_thumb.jpg" alt="9th image description" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/zim_thumb.jpg" alt="10th image description" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/sa_thumb.jpg" alt="11th image description" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/sl_thumb.jpg" alt="12th image description" /></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

How can i get the src of any next image from above code.

Comment: Do you mean, when you click on image 4?

Comment: Use the `next` method!

Comment: How to do it with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need like this one check it out.

```js
$( "li" ).click(function() {
  var current=$('li img').attr('src').split('/')[1].split('_')[0];
    alert(current);
  $('li img').attr('src','images/'+(++current)+'_thumb.jpg');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbs" class="content mThumbnailScroller">
<ul>
  <li><img src="images/1_thumb.jpg" alt="1st image description" /></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: $('.next').click(function() {
    var curr = $('#largeImage').attr('src'); ---------that is current img src
    var next = $('#thumbs ul li').find('img[src=' + curr + ']').next('img').attr('src');
    
 });